# Variadic template function with a template function as an argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm trying to compile the following:

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>

template <typename T>
void sort(T &container) {}

template <typename F, typename T, typename ...Tail>
void sort_containers(F sort_func, T &container, Tail &...tail) {
    sort_func(container);
    sort_containers(sort_func, tail...);
}

template <typename F, typename T>
void sort_containers(F sort_func, T &container) {
    sort_func(container);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> x = {1,2,3};
    std::vector<double> y = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
    std::array<char, 3> z = {{'d' , 'b', 'c'}};
    sort_containers(sort, x, y, z);
}
```

Which leads to the following compiler error with g++4.8:

```
error: no matching function for call to 
‘sort_containers(<unresolved overloaded function type>, 
std::vector<int>&, std::vector<double>&, std::array<char, 3u>&)’
```

I understand that I need to specify the template parameter for `sort` when passing it to `sort_containers`, but I'm not sure how this works in the presence of a variadic template function.

Comment: It works just like it would work with a non-variadic template `sort_three_containers`. That is, not too well. You need to pass not a function (template) but an object with a member function template that does the sorting, so that its instantiation happens at every recursive call to `sort_containers`.

Comment: With a non-variadic template I can do the following: http://ideone.com/jBg5yT, although I guess this example wouldn't extend to `sort_three_containers`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`template` functions are function factories, not functions.  They cannot be passed around directly.

Now, functors can be, and a relatively simple wrapper can turn an overload set of functions into a functor:

```
struct sort_functor {
   template<typename...Args>
   auto operator()(Args&&... args) const ->
   decltype(sort(std::forward<Args>(args)... ) )
   { return sort(std::forward<Args>(args)... ); }
};
```

which can be generated via macro, but not by `template`, because you cannot pass the overload set!  You then pass `sort_functor()` to your other `template`.

```
#define MAKE_OVERLOAD_FUNCTOR( NAME ) \
  struct CONCAT( NAME, _functor ) { \
    template<typename...Args> \
    auto operator()(Args&&... args) const -> \
    decltype(NAME(std::forward<Args>(args)... ) ) \
    { return NAME(std::forward<Args>(args)... ) } \
  };
```

There is a proposal to make generating the above functor automagically via further abuse of the `[]` tokens.

Comment: Pff, "abuse". I'm just leaning on the lambda syntax. :P

Comment: I said "*further* abuse" :) Lambda syntax was the initial abuse @xeo